# One year Interval mysql condition

Tags: mysql

Hello I am trying to write a case statement that has a 1 year interval in this case the year starts at April and ends march of the following year, however If for example march of this year is entered then it would be the end of last year due to the fact that, the year would have started from last year April

Have a look at the sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad042/1)

and this is the code that I have so far, note the

```
sum(case 
        when Month(py.pay_date) = 4 interval())1 year
        then amount end) yearly_amount
```

This is where I am having the major problem

Comment: what's the error message? (i'm assuming it's a syntax error)

Comment: `Month(py.pay_date) = 4 interval())1 year` --- what's this? Could you explain how you expect this exact expression to work?

Comment: Can you give an example of what data you would expect to see output?

Comment: I was attempting to do a 1 year calculation where the year would start from April and end March the following year

Comment: @dames: yes, and could you explain what the quoted expression means? Why did you write it in very that way? Where in the documentation you've found that syntax?

Comment: I know it was wrong But i was just trying thats why I came here for some help in fixing the problem, what what result I am expecting @dumperbox is the sum of the amount from april of this year to march of next year. Have a look at the fiddle you may see what I am saying

Comment: @dames: So instead of reading documentation you just wrote some random things expecting it will work, right?

Comment: No I tried my best based on my understanding then I didnt get it correct so i simply came and asked for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this for your `yearly_amount` calculation for the current year (starting in april and ending at the end of march in the next year):

```
sum(case 
        when py.pay_date >= STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-04-01'), '%Y-%m-%d') and
             py.pay_date <  STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-04-01'), '%Y-%m-%d') + interval 1 year
             then amount
        end) yearly_amount
```

[*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16e6b/19)

Comment: Thank you so much, I do appreciate greatly.